# After swapping batteries, truck is really dead, except the headlights.

Tags: electrical, battery

I removed battery from 1997 Tacoma to replace dead battery in Sienna Van and took dead battery to repair shop for testing. Repair shop tested and charged the battery. Now Tacoma is using a fully charged battery. However the only thing that works are the headlights. Ignition is completely dead, the ignition doesn't even 'click' when cranked. The dome lights are dead. It's like no juice is coming from the battery to anything but the headlights. Windows won't roll up or down.

Possible wrench in otherwise typical battery swap: After I removed the battery from the Tacoma to use in the Siennna. The windows were rolled down and the Tacoma had no power supply. I used jumper cables to connect from battery of Sienna and connected to battery terminals to Tacoma to provide power to roll up windows. This did not work.

Suppose, I crosswired the jumper cables to roll up the windows, could I have done something to explain why truck does not crank?

Comment: To clarify: so initially Battery A was in the Siena and went dead, and Battery B was in the Tacoma.  And now battery B is in the Siena and works, and battery A is in the Tacoma and doesn't work.  What exact types are the batteries?  Do they have similar ratings (amp-hours, cranking amps)?

Comment: Did you reconnect all of the positive leads going to the battery? Oft times manufacturers will have separate leads which energize the alternator, starter solenoid (while the main lead powers the starter itself), and accessories. You may want to see if you left something off.

Comment: @Nate E.Both batteries work. One in Sienna was dead, but I took to mechanic who charged it. Meanwhile I used functional battery from Tacoma and put it in Sienna. Eventually, the fully recharged battery from mechanic returned to Tacoma.

Comment: I mean, battery A doesn't work in the sense that it doesn't run the Tacoma.  What about the types and ratings?

Comment: The one in the Truck is a 12V with a 12.8 amperage rating after charging.

Comment: A fresh, fully charged battery will usually be in the 13.1-13.2vdc range. If it's 12.8v (assuming my meant volts there and not amperage) fully charged, I'd be keeping a close eye on it. Not that 12.8v isn't going to start a car, it's just lower than I'd expect for a fully charged battery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, something else happened which explains why the truck doesn't work. The truck didn't crank because the ALT-A (80-AMP) fuse tripped. I replaced the 80-AMP fuse as well as other fuses that also blew.

After replacing the fuses, the truck cranked, the interior lights burned, the radio played, and the windows rolled. Cross connecting battery cables to a charged battery did indeed trip the fuses.